# Handle HttpURLConnection redirect (NASA open API)

Tags: java, json, http

I'm writing a Java application that communicates with the NASA open apis. I've a class named NASAClient which exposes the required interface to achieve this task, but I'm facing with the following problem when dealing with the Earth Imagery API.

```
    public EarthImageryResponseObject earthImagery(double lon, double lat, String year, String mon, String day, boolean cloud_score) {
    String cs;
    if(cloud_score) cs = "True";
    else cs = "False";
    String url = "https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/earth/imagery?lon="
            + lon
            + "&lat=" 
            + lat
            + "&date="
            + year+"-"+mon+"-"+day
            + "&cloud_score="
            + cs 
            + "&api_key=" + api_key;
    try {
        String json = (read(getConnection(url)));
        return gson.fromJson(json, EarthImageryResponseObject.class);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }

}

private String read(HttpURLConnection conn) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((conn.getInputStream())));
    return readFromBufferedReader(br);
}

private String readFromBufferedReader(BufferedReader br) throws IOException {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line = br.readLine();
    while (line != null) {
        sb.append(line);
        line = br.readLine();
    }
    return sb.toString();
}

private HttpURLConnection getConnection(String url) throws IOException {
    HttpURLConnection connection;
    connection = createConnection(url);
    this.availability = connection.getHeaderField("X-RateLimit-Remaining");
    connection.setConnectTimeout(2000);
    this.last_resp = connection.getResponseCode();
    return connection;
}

private HttpURLConnection createConnection(String url) throws IOException {
    URL UniformResourceLocation = new URL(url);
    return (HttpURLConnection) UniformResourceLocation.openConnection();
}
```

When I call earthImagery with some standard parameters, I get the following url:

```
https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/earth/imagery?lon=100.75&lat=1.5&date=2017-01-01&cloud_score=False&api_key=[MY_KEY]
```

If I navigate to this url using curl or the browser, I get the expected Json serialized object, but when invoked within my application, I get a redirection link (with 301 response code) to an heroku app:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN"><title>Redirecting...</title><h1>Redirecting...</h1><p>You should be redirected automatically to target URL: <a href="http://earth-imagery-api.herokuapp.com/earth/imagery/?lon=100.75&amp;lat=1.5&amp;date=2017-01-01&amp;cloud_score=False">http://earth-imagery-api.herokuapp.com/earth/imagery/?lon=100.75&amp;lat=1.5&amp;date=2017-01-01&amp;cloud_score=False</a>.  If not click the link.
```

If I try to open a connection to such link, as explained [here](https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-httpurlconnection-follow-redirect-example/) ,or open it in a browser it returns an error message (parameters are wrong). Really don't know what I am doing wrong. This strategy is the same for the other API I'm using in the application, and they work. Here it follows the stacktrace

```
Exception in thread "Thread-1" com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:226)
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:927)
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:892)
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:841)
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:813)
at com.alexfoglia.nasaapi.NASAClient.earthImagery(NASAClient.java:151)
at com.alexfoglia.nasaapi.gui.EarthPanel.lambda$2(EarthPanel.java:127)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $
at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.beginObject(JsonReader.java:385)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:215)
... 7 more
```

And that's because i'm expecting a Json object, but I get a String (html redirect page).

Comment: That's exactly what I've done, but it returns an error message telling parameters are wrong. I think this is due to the fact that a single get to the provided url earth-imagery-api.herokuapp.com loses the informations about my api key, that is mandatory. I thought it was in the cookies or in other connection parameters, but no, even if I get the cookies from the first connection and add them to the second, it won't work. However thanks

Comment: `catch(IOException e) {...}` - print the statcktrace, do not silently swallow exceptions

Comment: you're right, I've changed the code several times. I add the exception stack trace in the question

Comment: This problem has nothing to do with the redirect, the problem is with the JSON parsing `return gson.fromJson(json, EarthImageryResponseObject.class);`  try printing out the json first, to examine

Comment: The json string is exactly the string "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC " etc..." that contains the redirection url

Comment: I am confused Alex, you have posted a link showing how to handle redirects, but you have not shown this in your code e.g. `if (redirect) {

  // get redirect url from "location" header field
  String newUrl = conn.getHeaderField("Location");`

Comment: I know you're confused, i am too. I tried that solution, but when done, the "Location" header field is exactly the same url, and not the heroku url, and the string obtained is always the same (the page telling that the link is to the heroku app). I've also manipulated the string to open a new connection to the heroku link, but if I do things this way, the json string is a json object, but it is: {
  "msg": "Bad Request incorrect field passed. Allowed request fields for earth/imagery method are 'lat', 'lon', 'address', 'dataset', 'date', 'cloud_score', 'dim'", 
  "service_version": "v1"
}

Comment: How on earth did they put Men on the moon?

Comment: Sorry Mate, I do not think I can be of any more help.  I tried directly using the link you gave me (with nasa url) but as I do not have API key, it did not work.  I suggest that approach this angle, and/or use a browser and inspect what packets are being sent.

Comment: you can use DEMO_KEY as an api key if you want to manually test apis :) it has some limitation on the daily amount of permitted usage, but it works. a big thank you

Comment: Using the DEMO_KEY I get a 400 error when I try to conenct using `http`, I note that your URL is `https`

Comment: https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/earth/imagery/?lon=100.75&lat=1.5&date=2017-01-01&cloud_score=False&api_key=DEMO_KEY this is the correct link. If i open a connection using openssl to api.nasa.gov port 443, and after that I send a GET /planetary/etc... it returns the json object. I'll try to deal with SSL sockets

Comment: i solved using both httpurlconnection and sslsocket :)

Comment: Good to hear, maybe you should post as an answer, Oh you did

Comment: yes i was doing so :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved using both HttpURLConnection and SSLSocket. The first connection obtain the redirect link, that is reached not by another httpurlconnection, instead, a SSLSocket is used to get to this link.

```
public EarthImageryResponseObject earthImagery(double lon, double lat, String year, String mon, String day, boolean cloud_score) {
    String cs;
    if(cloud_score) cs = "True";
    else cs = "False";
    String url = "https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/earth/imagery?lon="
            + lon
            + "&lat=" 
            + lat
            + "&date="
            + year+"-"+mon+"-"+day
            + "&cloud_score="
            + cs 
            + "&api_key=" + api_key;
    try {
        HttpURLConnection conn = getConnection(url);
        String new_url = conn.getHeaderField("Location");
        SSLSocketFactory factory =
                    (SSLSocketFactory)SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
        SSLSocket socket =
                    (SSLSocket)factory.createSocket("api.nasa.gov", 443);
        socket.startHandshake();
        socket.getOutputStream().write(("GET "+new_url+"\n").getBytes());
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                                        new InputStreamReader(
                                        socket.getInputStream()));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
                    sb.append(inputLine);
        in.close();
        socket.close();
        String json = sb.toString();
        System.out.println(json);
        return gson.fromJson(json, EarthImageryResponseObject.class);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want your code to automatically follow redirects then set this flag

```
connection.setFollowRedirects (true);
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#setFollowRedirects(boolean)

Comment: still tried, the result is the same (indeed, this flag is true by default)